# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, while trying to play video

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using `AVFoundation` kit to play a local video

I tried this code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var player: AVPlayer?

@IBOutlet weak var videoViewContainer: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeVideoPlayerWithVideo()
}

func initializeVideoPlayerWithVideo() {

    // get the path string for the video from assets
    let videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Air Bike", ofType: "mov")
    guard let unwrappedVideoPath = videoString else {return}

    // convert the path string to a url
    let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: unwrappedVideoPath)

    // initialize the video player with the url
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)

    // create a video layer for the player
    let layer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    // make the layer the same size as the container view
    layer.frame = videoViewContainer.bounds

    // make the video fill the layer as much as possible while keeping its aspect size
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    // add the layer to the container view
    videoViewContainer.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}


@IBAction func playVideoButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // play the video if the player is initialized
    player?.play()
}
}
```

I've trying a few different approaches and I'm still getting the same error message can someone How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see any unsafe optional unwrapping here except in this line `@IBOutlet weak var videoViewContainer: UIView!` , did you set the outlet correctly ?? If you are not sure, try to print the `videoViewContainer` in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yes the outlet have been set correctly  I've removed them and then connected them once again still the same is there anything else I can try? Thanks

Comment: which line you get the crash ???

Comment: Is `videoURL` getting assigned a value correctly?

Comment: I get the crash at line 41 and the URL is sent correctly I just removed the whole view controller and created a new one ,but I still get the same error....

Comment: And which line would „line 41“ here be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func initializeVideoPlayerWithVideo() {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jagdeep", ofType:".MOV") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }

    self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    // create a video layer for the player
    let layer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    // make the layer the same size as the container view
    layer.frame = videoViewContainer.bounds

    // make the video fill the layer as much as possible while keeping its aspect size
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    // add the layer to the container view
    videoViewContainer.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    player?.play()
}
```

**HERE IS MY VIDEO NAME jagdeep and type .MOV** AND its working on my side. It's problem in your code where you using type mov. I just drag a video name jagdeep.MOV to my project and use Your code. its ok [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
**use** 

layer.frame = videoViewContainer.layer.bounds
```

instead of

```
 // make the layer the same size as the container view
    layer.frame = videoViewContainer.bounds
```

Comment: It's still the same line 41 islayer.frame = videoViewContainer.bounds

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response seems like the file cannot be found here is a screenshot from my project what could be the reason the video is located in my main folder! [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmo3c.png)

Comment: Ok so I added the file in build phase and I get the same error message again..... I Just don't understand what could be wrong.....